# How to stop infinite while loop python emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I wrote this code:

```
x = 0
while x == 0:
      print 'd'
```

When I type C-c! and C-c C-c the code runs.

Now the question is: How I stop the execution of that code?

Comment: You can press C-c C-\ to quit, and C-c C-c to break.

Comment: You can aslo kill Python process in the buffer list or ibuffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks for our answers. Finaly I got the solution. Here is my step by step how-to.

Credits to **Omri Barel, Pavel Repin, jmdeldin**

Startpoint is: infinite while loop in pythontests.py file,

1. C-c ! (open the python shell)(you see two windows "buffers", cursor is in the python shell)
2. C-x o (switch to other window "buffer") (now is the pythontests.py file highlited)
3. C-c C-C (execute the code)(the lines begin to move and count :))
4. C-x o (switch to other window "buffer") (now is the python shell highlited)
5. C-c C-c (stops running process) (now you see the Trackback message)

In my case I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/python-4684wEr.py", line 3, in <module>
    print 'd'
KeyboardInterrupt
```

And here is the screencast how it works:  http://youtu.be/1MbfCHusF9c

Comment: This does not always work.  In many cases it just appends C-c C-c to the *Python* buffer repeatedly without stopping the underlying execution.  I have yet to determine exactly why this happens or how to stop it from running in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the `*Python*` buffer and type `C-q C-c` to interrupt the script. `C-q` (`quoted-insert`) is used to insert control characters because `C-c` would be intercepted by Emacs. It works in the shell modes too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want C-g which will stop running the current command.